# could not able to understand Project Euler 18. "Maximum path sum I"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, arithmetic, project-euler

According to question,

By starting at the top of the triangle below and moving to adjacent numbers on the row below, the maximum total from top to bottom is 23.

```
   3
  7 4
 2 4 6
8 5 9 3
```

That is, `3 + 7 + 4 + 9 = 23.`

I think, the largest number should be from top to bottom is `3 + 7 + 6 + 9 = 25` instead of `23`.
If we will take all the largest number from the rows.

Is my understanding wrong?

Because when I wrote the program for

```
                         75
                        95 64
                      17 47 82
                     18 35 87 10
                   20 04 82 47 65
                  19 01 23 75 03 34
                 88 02 77 73 07 63 67
                99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92
               41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33
              41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29
             53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14
            70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57
           91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48
          63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31
         04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23
```

Program.c

```
int main()
{
    int max = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    int i, j, ans;
    int myarr[15];
    int arr[15][15] = {
        75,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
        95,  64,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
        17,  47,  82,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
        18,  35,  87,  10,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
        20,  04,  82,  47,  65,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
        19,  01,  23,  75,  03,  34,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
        88,  02,  77,  73,  07,  63,  67,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
        99,  65,  04,  28,  06,  16,  70,  92,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
        41,  41,  26,  56,  83,  40,  80,  70,  33,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
        41,  48,  72,  33,  47,  32,  37,  16,  94,  29,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
        53,  71,  44,  65,  25,  43,  91,  52,  97,  51,  14,   0,   0,   0,   0, 
        70,  11,  33,  28,  77,  73,  17,  78,  39,  68,  17,  57,   0,   0,   0, 
        91,  71,  52,  38,  17,  14,  91,  43,  58,  50,  27,  29,  48,   0,   0, 
        63,  66,  04,  68,  89,  53,  67,  30,  73,  16,  69,  87,  40,  31,   0, 
        04,  62,  98,  27,  23,   9,  70,  98,  73,  93,  38,  53,  60,  04,  23
    };
    for(i = 0, ans = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 15; j++)
        {
           temp = arr[i][j];
           if(temp > max)
           {
               max = temp;
           }
        }

        ans += max;
        cout << "Max of row " << i << " is " << max << endl;
        max = 0;
    }
    std::cout << ans << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

I got the answer as `1313`.

But it says it is a wrong answer.
Please help me understanding the question., where I am going wrong?

Comment: You want to find a "connected" path, going from the top to the bottom row, in each step moving a "half-step" to the right or to the left.

Comment: @mrf: - Could you please elaborate?

Comment: In your example 7 and 6 are not adjacent. (You need to move 3/2 steps to the right from 7 to 6.)

Comment: Doesn't the Project Euler site itself have a forum for discussing the questions?

Comment: @GEdgar It's only available to those who have solved the relevant question, I believe. The PE people are extremely anti-collaboration.

Answer (score 3):

You can only step downward to the left or downward to the right from where you are.  If you choose the $7$ in the second row, your only choices for the third row are $2$ or $4$, not $6$

Comment: Still I am confued, why can't I choose `6`?

Comment: It is not adjacent (next) to $7$

Answer (score 1):

In addition to people pointing out why you are wrong. I think you would benefit from someone telling you how to solve this problem

The correct algorithm should be working backward. Look up Bellman principle. This problem is often as used as a first example problem in introducing dynamic maximisation problem.

Edit: someone pointed out i shouldn't post a solution! I think the op would benefit from my relatively vague hint. It would reduce the complexity of your problem significantly!

Comment: Actually, I think it's a bad idea to post solutions to problems from project Euler.

Comment: @mrf what is project Euler, my precious?

Answer (score 1):

You need to see the diagram like this:

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
&&&3\\
&&\swarrow&&\searrow\\
&&7&&4\\
&\swarrow&&\searrow\swarrow&&\searrow\\
&2&&4&&6\\
\swarrow&&\searrow\swarrow&&\searrow\swarrow&&\searrow\\
8&&5&&9&&3\\
\end{array}$$

so that you see there is no path from the $7$ to the $6$.